# How to round float to n decimal places including 0 in the end in Python

Tags: python, rounding

I need to make function which returns rounded pi to n decimal places as string. For example pi_digits(3) should return '3.142', pi_digits(0) returns '3'. Here is my code:

```
from math import pi

def pi_digits(n):
    if n > 0:
        return str(round(pi, n))
    else:
        return str(round(pi))
```

But pi_digits(12) returns '3.14159265359' instead of '3.141592653590'. How to consider 0 while rounding?

Comment: It is just convention to leave off tailing zeros, but it still is there. What happens if you do pi _ digits(13)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string formatting instead of calling `str` on the rounded output which does not behave consistently across Python versions. In Python 2, for example, you can never get a character count precision beyond 12 when calling `str` on a float (i.e. with `float.__str__`). `str.format` removes such discrepancies:

```
from math import pi

def pi_digits(n):
    return '{:.{}f}'.format(pi, n)

print(pi_digits(12))
# 3.141592653590

print(pi_digits(3))
# 3.142

print(pi_digits(0))
# 3
```

Comment: `pi_digits(-1)` will raise `ValueError`, you need to add the `if .. else` to keep it safe.

Comment: @Szabolcs Depends. Anyone passing `-1` as floating point precision should be prepared to have an error thrown in their face :)

Comment: The original function has error handling, at least provide an approach as safe as the original one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
'{:.{width}f}'.format(pi, width=12)
```

Output:

```
'3.141592653590'
```